# How to paint the background color in special level in TVirtualStringTree

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

I try to paint a hightline text using backgroundcolor in all sepecial level of VirtualStringTree. It look like a selected nodes for all same level. 
The code below doesn't work. Please someone give a direction.

```
procedure TMainForm.Tree1PaintText(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; const TargetCanvas: TCanvas; Node: PVirtualNode; Column: TColumnIndex; TextType: TVSTTextType);
var  Data: PNodeData;LEVEL:INTEGER;  tree1node,tree4Node: PVirtualNode;
begin 
    Data := Tree1.GetNodeData(Node);
    Level := tree1.GetNodeLevel(node);

 case column of
     0:begin
        if Level = 0 then BEGIN
               TargetCanvas.Font.Style := TargetCanvas.Font.Style + [fsBold];
               TargetCanvas.Font.Color :=CLyellow;
               targetcanvas.Brush.Color :=clgreen;//don't work
               targetcanvas.Brush.Style :=bssolid;     

             END;
            if  Level = 1 then BEGIN
                  TargetCanvas.Font.Color :=CLaqua; 
                  targetcanvas.Brush.Color :=clgreen;
            end;
       end;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VT fills the cell background sooner, in the **PrepareCell** method to be more specific. So it's too late for attempts to setup the canvas brush. Try to fill the node rectangle from the **OnBeforeCellPaint** event instead:

```
procedure TForm1.VirtualStringTree1BeforeCellPaint(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree;
  TargetCanvas: TCanvas; Node: PVirtualNode; Column: TColumnIndex;
  CellPaintMode: TVTCellPaintMode; CellRect: TRect; var ContentRect: TRect);
var
  R: TRect;
begin
  if CellPaintMode = cpmPaint then
  begin
    R := Sender.GetDisplayRect(Node, Column, True, False, True);
    R.Offset(0, -R.Top);
    case Sender.GetNodeLevel(Node) of
      0: TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := $0000F9FF;
      1: TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := $0000BFFF;
      2: TargetCanvas.Brush.Color := $000086FF;
    end;
    TargetCanvas.FillRect(R);
  end;
end;
```

Preview:

[image]

Comment: Congratulations on reaching 5k rep! :)

Comment: @Victoria Thanks, just found the answer, couple of questions though:
1) Why to use an extra TRect? ContentRect is not good enough?
2) Ah no, need to check first

Comment: @Victoria Yes found, 'toFullRowSelect' completely clears all what has been drawn in OnBeforeCellPaint

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `eaColor` as erase action in `OnBeforeItemErase` event:

```
procedure TMainForm.Tree1BeforeItemErase(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; TargetCanvas: TCanvas;
          Node: PVirtualNode; ItemRect: TRect; var ItemColor: TColor; var EraseAction: TItemEraseAction);
begin
   if not Sender.Selected[Node] then begin
      case Sender.GetNodeLevel(Node) of
        0: ItemColor := clgreen;
        1: ItemColor := clAgua;
      end;
      EraseAction := eaColor;
   end;
end;
```

Comment: hi, i test the code.it can  show the background color in different column.    "itemcolor "seem only for fillrect all item .  if fillrect only in text  of item (exclude the space) ,how to improve?.thanks

Comment: Yes, the ItemErase is for whole row (ie all columns), if you need more control you probably have to use custom draw.